# How to merge multiple transparent pngs with different size into one image without cropping, using PHP GD library?

Tags: php, merge, png, php-gd

I would like to merge multiple pngs with transparent background into one image. Images have different sizes and because of this, when images are placed over the top of each other, only within the size of the uppermost image are shown the parts of the merged images.

It's like the last image applies like a mask for the images merged before. I would like to see all the images merged with their original size, without cropping the parts hanging over the size of the last image.

Here is the code I'm using currently:

```
$images = array();
    foreach (scandir($this->img_dir) as $key => $dirname) {
        if(!strstr($dirname, "."))
        {
            if(isset($_GET[$dirname])) 
            {
                foreach ($this->layer_order as $lkey => $order) {
                    if($lkey == $dirname)
                        $images[$order] = glob($this->img_dir . "/" . $dirname . "/" . $_GET[$dirname] . ".png");
                }
            }
        }
    }


    $destination = imagecreatetruecolor(458, 600);


    imagealphablending($destination, true);
    imagesavealpha($destination, true);

    ksort($images);
    foreach($images as $key => $value) {        
        foreach ($value as $fn) {
            // Load image
            $source = imagecreatefrompng($fn);
            //$source = $this->resize_image($source, 50, 50, 2);

            // Copy over image
            imagecopy($destination, $source, 10, 50, 0, 0, 458, 600);

            // Free memory
            imagedestroy($source);
        }
    }

    return $destination;
```

Comment: The source images are cropped because `imagecopy` specifies to copy only from x0, y0 (params 5 & 6) to x458, y600 (params 7 & 8).  Your statement "all the images merged with their original size" is at odds with your code: `imagecreatetruecolor(458, 600);`.  You either need to make `$destination` bigger (at least as big as the biggest source image) or resize the source images to fit in 458x600. What do you want to do?

Comment: I would like to make an app where people can click on parts images of a door and the script will combine them into one final variation. The size of the result image should always be 458x600 and the different sized images should merged within this size. My problem was that the door image is bigger than the doorhandle image which is the last one and within this 458x600 the parts of the merged images were only visible within the size of the doorhandle image and the rest of the 458x600 final image was black. I wanted to put the doorhandle on the door as people click on that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best solution for what I tried to achive, but after several attempts and some research I used a fairly simple method to avoid the last image in the merging queue, mask the other images with it's relatively small size. This way every image will be merged and positioned accordingly the user wants, inside the specified canvas size, with their transparency.

I post the whole content of the function in case if someone needs a similar solution. This is a function inside a class.

```
    $images = array();

    // Foreach loop to set images order and creating an array with image paths using params from $_GET before merging
    foreach (scandir($this->img_dir) as $key => $dirname) {
        if(!strstr($dirname, "."))
        {
            if(isset($_GET[$dirname])) 
            {
                foreach ($this->layer_order as $lkey => $order) {
                    if($lkey == $dirname) {
                        $imageArray = glob($this->img_dir . "/" . $dirname . "/" . ($dirname == "door" && isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type']."/" : "") . $_GET[$dirname] . ".png");
                        foreach ($imageArray as $imgPath) {
                            $images[$order] = $imgPath;
                        }
                    }       
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Allocate new image
    $destination = imagecreatetruecolor($this->canvas_width, $this->canvas_height);

    imagealphablending($destination, false);
    $col = imagecolorallocatealpha($destination, 255, 255, 255, 127);
    imagefilledrectangle($destination, 0, 0, $this->canvas_width, $this->canvas_height, $col);
    imagealphablending($destination, true);

    // Sort order
    ksort($images);

    // Merging images
    foreach($images as $key => $fn) {

        // Load image
        if(strstr($fn, "handle")) 
        {
            $source = $this->resizePng($fn, 0.18, 100, 205);
            imagecopy($destination, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->canvas_width, $this->canvas_height);
        }
        elseif (strstr($fn, "glass")) 
        {
            // Create a background image by filling a canvas with small image tiles. Params: $file, $shrink_ratio_percent, $column_size, $stretch
            $source = $this->multiplyMergeAndResizePngs($fn, 0.2095, 3, 3.6);
            // Applying mask on images based on black and white patterns
            if ($this->glass_mask)
                $source = $this->createMask($source, $this->glass_mask);
            imagecopy($destination, $source, 118, 28, 0, 0, $this->canvas_width, $this->canvas_height);
        }
        elseif (strstr($fn, "door")) 
        {    
            $source = imagecreatefrompng($fn);
            imagecopy($destination, $source, 32, 0, 0, 0, $this->canvas_width, $this->canvas_height);
        } else {
            $source = imagecreatefrompng($fn);
            imagecopy($destination, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->canvas_width, $this->canvas_height);
        }

        imagealphablending($destination, true);

        // Free memory
        imagedestroy($source);
    }

    return $destination;
```